# action bar buttons not taking on background color and can't change background window color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to do what I thought would be simple but after two days of searching for an answer, have given up. I am writing an app and I want the user to be able to switch from the Holo dark theme to the Holo light theme via preferences. Holo Light will be white window background with black text, and Holo dark will be the inverse. I also want them to be able to set the color of the action bar to something they like. Problem I'm having is when I succeed in flipping the background of the main window (by using android:background in styles.xml), the action bar icon and buttons do not take on the color of the action bar. If I use android:windowBackground in styles.xml, the action bar now looks fine and changes color, but the main window background does not. Here is the xml from styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="ThemeHoloDark" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#0734f9</item>
    <!-- blue -->

</style>

<style name="ThemeHoloLight" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f90707</item>
</style>
```

The code I am using to switch theme is this:

```
    if (themeLight == true )
        setTheme( R.style.ThemeHoloLight);
    else
        setTheme( R.style.ThemeHoloDark);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    setActionBarTheme(this, actionBar );
```

Here are some screenshots of what I'm talking about. The first couple show the action bar flipping from light to dark when the preferences are selected:
--Apparently I don't have enough reputation points to post images. :(

I have tried pretty much everything I have found on the web but must be missing something. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can host your screenshots in website and provide the link here. However, did you look at on [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground) to setup your ActionBar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a seperate custom `actionBarStyle` like this . `android:background` in the `ActionBarStyle` will set the background for action bar.

```
<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/HoloTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/Red</item>
</style>
```

and set it to the main custom style .`android:background` in the `ThemeHoloLight` will set the background for window.

```
 <style name="ThemeHoloLight" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/DarkGreen</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

You can also change the action bar title color like this

```
<style name="HoloTitleText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Hope this is what your looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same issue. I've changed styles.xml to be as you suggested, and updated the manifest to reference the new master theme. WHen I am in the preferences screen, the action bar takes on whatever color I choose and displays that color for the icon/title as well. When I exit preferences and go back to main activity, center portion of the action is shown in the new color, but the icon/title, drawer and search icons all have black backrounds no matter what color the rest of the action bar is showing.

Comment: What was the issue now? . can you show some screenshot

Comment: I wish i could, but i don't have enough reputation points to paste an image.

Comment: I'll try and describe textually:  [OO<icon> <title> OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO<drawer> <search>]. 'O' represents orange color on the action bar, <icon>, <title>, <drawer> and <search> are all shown with black background.